# Foley Mic recomendations < 1500 Euro

Tags: microphone, foley

I have some Budget, so i want to get a good Foley Mic. For now I tested the Rode ngt2 and sennheiser mkh 416.

Do you have any recomendations for an all around foley mic?

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. I bought a Studio Projects B1 and a TLM 103 now and those are great for everything :D i will buy a second B1 for stereo recordings. (the tlm 103 i use mainly for speech/vocals). Also i really liked the akg 414 which is my next buy.

Comment: And I use NTG2 and Sennheiser MKH416 if i want less room tone on my Recodring. Also for things like footsteps i tried lavaliermics (sennheiser ew 100 eng) attached to my feet and it gave some really cool sound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a wide range to choose from, my first choice would be the AKG 414 XLS, which is well within your budget.

http://www.akg.com/C414+XLS-1039.html?pid=1024

Comment: Oh you can choose all type of characteristics, that is great. I will test it in a local store thx.

Comment: The 414 is one of the best mics around, I would second that. It's not a shotgun, so as long as you have a good quiet work environment it has every polar pattern you would need otherwise. Great price. Also will come in handy if you find yourself recording voice for anything.

Comment: Yeah heard some tests on voiceovers. i think this is the winner :)

Answer (score 1):

I use a united minorities greeny for foley work. Amazing sound and cheaper than an u87.
If that's too expensive try the rode nt 55. 
they're not the best ones out there, but quite decent for footsteps, especially since they're often used on set, so the foley blends nicely with ot

Answer (score 1):

Neumann KMR81 - great for matching into production audio & no freq bump like the 416 has

Answer (score 0):

Get two!

Suggest TLM 103 - (super quiet) &

Small dia MKH416 (which has all sorts of other uses too (obviously!))

Buy 2nd hand and you might be on budget

rich

Comment: Thx i give them a try :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a good foley studio? If not buying a  TLM103 or other LDC will only create issues (a lot of bad acoustics in recordings).  (this is actually the reason for me to not buy a LDC at the moment).
Have you looked at getting a supercardiod like the sennheiser mkh(80)50 or other SDC's like schoeps mk40?

Comment: until now i recorded in my sleeping room and when i need a very dry signal i have a very good vocal booth with enough space to foley around :)

Comment: Yeah now i have a good room which i am very happy. Its not dead, but lively. Together with the total dead vocal boot hand courtyard, i have a nice bunch of places to go!

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking at the NTG2, which i was, I was told by Watson Wu to just save up and get the ntg3. Searching around, it looks like he's right, it is a substantially better mic and not very expensive for the usability.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest Earthworks QTC 50.
http://www.earthworksaudio.com/microphones/qtc-series-2/qtc50/
It is quiet, 3Hz-50KHz. Let you record at hi sampling rate to down speed for special effects.

Comment: Partially true:  assuming the recorder preamps and A/D signal path are capable of that frequency response.  Some recorders may sample up to 96k or 192k, but not actually be responsive beyond 20kHz as far as mic input goes.  So yes, what said is definitely correct assuming the entire signal path is capable to sustaining that frequency response.

Comment: This tends to be why the 7-series Sound Devices are sought after because they certainly capable of sustaining that frequency response through and through for something like the QTC 50 or MKH 8000-series

Answer (score 0):

I love my MKH416, excellent microphone, I about to finish a short which I had to create all the foley in it and it served me well. I like what rob suggested, you don't have to spend premium price to get a good mic, I bought mine 2nd hand and never looked back.

Due to its directivity it will also work well if you don't have good room acoustics, foley aims at recording the sound and not its surroundings.

Comment: Yeah the MKH 416 has a really good TV like sound is you know what i mean. I use it to boom on the set.

Answer (score 0):

I will echo Michael's comments about the Rode NTG-3. Its a durable and great sounding mic that has been my sole foley mic for 2 years now.